# Cannot copy files to shared directory on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions

I am new to Ubuntu. I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and created a folder which I shared access with another workstation (Windows). From windows, I can access the shared folder, but I cannot copy or paste. I receive this message:

```
You need permission to perform this action
```

[image: Windows Message]

Could someone guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: How did you configure the shared directory on Ubuntu? Could you [edit] your question to include the steps? This may reveal something that was missed 

Comment: do this in your ubuntu to the directory you have shared. chmod -R 777 /directory_path

Comment: if you have two os(ubuntu and windows) on your system, restart and enter to your ubuntu, then shut down, and start with windows

Comment: @matigo

in Ubuntu, i created folder in dev/sdb/. "Shared Files" then i right click and local network share, after that a message was prompt that need to install Samba, i clicked install, after  installed, i managed to see the shared folder i created from my windows PC and access it - "Administrator username and password promt". I inputted the admin account of ubuntu. then i am trying to paste a file to that shared folder, i dont have permission

Comment: @zabiullah i have tried this - 

administrator@kpc-server:/media/administrator/Common Files/Shared Files$ sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/sdb

Still cant paste a file. please check if i did correct of  what you've said

Comment: you are doing it on disk, don't do it like that, do it on directory itself.

Comment: @zabiullah thank you bro it works!